# What precautions should I take when participating in Air B'n'B as a host?

Tags: security, airbnb

I'm thinking about participating in [Air B'n'B](https://www.airbnb.com/) as a host. I'm not really worried about my potential guest, otherwise I wouldn't participate. However, I want to take some precautions so that I don't get scammed or robbed or whatever. Today I thought about these precautions, but besides copying the passport and only accept guest with a good rating I couldn't think of anything else. Are there any more precautions I should consider?

Comment: Random, a friend was telling me that you need to be registered as a host with the govt in Canada.  I hadn't heard that.  Might be worth checking on the legal requirements in your country

Comment: @MarkMayo in France subletting is forbidden. So unless you are the owner (or have an agreement with the owner) if you get robbed insurance doesn't work, so you really need to trust the subletter.

Comment: @Vince - yeah, there's a whole legal section on their website about what you need to investigate.

Comment: Also, you might be breaking national laws if you don't declare the resulting income.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you can probably look at the [safety tips for Couchsurfing hosts](http://www.couchsurfing.org/safety/tips), as that'll provide some good suggestions:

- Set your expectations clearly
- Read requests clearly, make sure they 'sound' ok
- Don’t give out your personal information until you feel comfortable
- Inform your roommates, landlords, or neighbors
- Make sure your guest understands your rules and expectations
- Talk about the guidelines of the house
- Communicate and show respect
- and most importantly, it's **ok to say no.**  You should never feel pressured to take someone on.

Comment: CAN AirBnB hosts say no?

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee Yes - see the ["decline" option](https://www.airbnb.com/help/question/hosting/28).  You may not feel comfortable with them, or you may have friends staying, or be out of town yourself.